# WebRtc Android showing blank screen for both local and remote videoviews and audio not transmitted, but the data is showing in database when active

Tags: android, kotlin, webrtc, native, videocall

I have a webrtc android videocall activity. Both local and remote video is showing as blank and the audio is also not audible but in firebase it shows when user is active and sdp, ice is showing properly.
Here is my code. Please let me know if you can see what's wrong here. Thanks!

```
data class VideoRenderers(private var localView: SurfaceViewRenderer?, private var remoteView: SurfaceViewRenderer?) {
    val localRenderer: (VideoFrame) -> Unit = { f ->
        localView?.onFrame(f) ?: sink(f)
    }
    val remoteRenderer: (VideoFrame) -> Unit = { frame ->
        remoteView?.onFrame(frame) ?: sink(frame)
    }


    fun updateViewRenders(localView: SurfaceViewRenderer, remoteView: SurfaceViewRenderer) {
        this.localView = localView
        this.remoteView = remoteView
    }
    private fun sink(frame: VideoFrame) {
        Log.w("VideoRenderer", "Missing surface view, dropping frame")
        frame.release()
    }
}


class VideoCallSession(
        private val context: Context,
        private val isOfferingPeer: Boolean,
        private val onStatusChangedListener: (VideoCallStatus) -> Unit,
        private val signaler: FirebaseSignaler,
        val videoRenderers: VideoRenderers) {

    private var peerConnection: PeerConnection? = null
    private var videoSource: VideoSource? = null
    private var audioSource: AudioSource? = null

    private var mediaStream: MediaStream? = null
    private var videoCapturer: VideoCapturer? = null
    private var videoTrack: VideoTrack? = null

    private val eglBase = EglBase.create()


    private val videoHeight = 1280
    private val videoWidth = 720
    private val videoFPS = 30

    val renderContext: EglBase.Context
        get() = eglBase.eglBaseContext

    class SimpleRTCEventHandler(
            private val onIceCandidateCb: (IceCandidate) -> Unit,
            private val onAddStreamCb: (MediaStream) -> Unit,
            private val onRemoveStreamCb: (MediaStream) -> Unit) : PeerConnection.Observer {

        override fun onIceCandidate(candidate: IceCandidate?) {
            if (candidate != null) onIceCandidateCb(candidate)

        }

        override fun onAddStream(stream: MediaStream?) {
            if (stream != null) onAddStreamCb(stream)

        }

        override fun onRemoveStream(stream: MediaStream?) {
            if (stream != null) onRemoveStreamCb(stream)
        }

        override fun onDataChannel(chan: DataChannel?) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onDataChannel: $chan")
        }

        override fun onIceConnectionReceivingChange(p0: Boolean) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onIceConnectionReceivingChange: $p0")
            Log.d(TAG, " videocall onCreate: here 6")

        }

        override fun onIceConnectionChange(newState: PeerConnection.IceConnectionState?) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onIceConnectionChange: $newState")
        }

        override fun onIceGatheringChange(newState: PeerConnection.IceGatheringState?) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onIceGatheringChange: $newState")
        }

        override fun onSignalingChange(newState: PeerConnection.SignalingState?) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onSignalingChange: $newState")
        }

        override fun onIceCandidatesRemoved(candidates: Array<out IceCandidate>?) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onIceCandidatesRemoved: $candidates")
        }

        override fun onRenegotiationNeeded() {
            Log.w(TAG, "onRenegotiationNeeded")
        }

        override fun onAddTrack(receiver: RtpReceiver?, streams: Array<out MediaStream>?) {}
    }

    private val factory: PeerConnectionFactory by lazy {

        //Initialize PeerConnectionFactory globals.
        val initializationOptions = PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(context.applicationContext)
//                .setEnableVideoHwAcceleration(true)
        .createInitializationOptions()
        PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(initializationOptions)

        //Create a new PeerConnectionFactory instance - using Hardware encoder and decoder.
        val options = PeerConnectionFactory.Options()
        options.networkIgnoreMask = 0
        val defaultVideoEncoderFactory = DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(
                renderContext, /* enableIntelVp8Encoder */true, /* enableH264HighProfile */true)
        val defaultVideoDecoderFactory = DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(renderContext)
        PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
                .setOptions(options)
                .setVideoEncoderFactory(defaultVideoEncoderFactory)
                .setVideoDecoderFactory(defaultVideoDecoderFactory)
                .createPeerConnectionFactory()
    }


    init {

        signaler.messageHandler = this::onMessage
        this.onStatusChangedListener(VideoCallStatus.DIALING)
        executor.execute(this::init)
    }

    private fun init() {
        Log.d(TAG, " videocall onCreate: here 9")

        val iceServers = arrayListOf(
                PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("stun:stun.l.google.com:19302").createIceServer()
        )

        createPeerConnection(iceServers)
        setupMediaDevices()

        call()
    }

    private fun call() {
        val ref = FirebaseData.getCallStatusReference(signaler.callerID)

        ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean::class.java)!!) {
                    ref.removeEventListener(this)

                    onStatusChangedListener(VideoCallStatus.CONNECTING)
                    start()
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(e: DatabaseError) {
                Log.e(TAG, "databaseError:", e.toException())
                ref.removeEventListener(this)
            }
        })
    }


    private fun createPeerConnection(iceServers: List<PeerConnection.IceServer>) {
        val rtcConfig = PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(iceServers)
        rtcConfig.apply {
            // TCP candidates are only useful when connecting to a server that supports ICE-TCP.
            tcpCandidatePolicy = PeerConnection.TcpCandidatePolicy.DISABLED
            bundlePolicy = PeerConnection.BundlePolicy.MAXBUNDLE
            rtcpMuxPolicy = PeerConnection.RtcpMuxPolicy.REQUIRE
            continualGatheringPolicy = PeerConnection.ContinualGatheringPolicy.GATHER_CONTINUALLY

            enableCpuOveruseDetection = true
            enableDtlsSrtp = true
            // Use ECDSA encryption.
            keyType = PeerConnection.KeyType.ECDSA
        }

        val rtcEvents = SimpleRTCEventHandler(this::handleLocalIceCandidate, this::addRemoteStream, this::removeRemoteStream)

        peerConnection = factory.createPeerConnection(rtcConfig, rtcEvents)
    }


    private fun start() {
        signaler.init()
        executor.execute(this::maybeCreateOffer)
    }

    private fun maybeCreateOffer() {
        if (isOfferingPeer) {
            peerConnection?.createOffer(SDPCreateCallback(this::createDescriptorCallback), defaultPcConstraints())
        }
    }

    private fun defaultPcConstraints(): MediaConstraints {
        val pcConstraints = MediaConstraints()
        pcConstraints.optional.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", "true"))
        pcConstraints.mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveAudio", "true"))
        pcConstraints.mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveVideo", "true"))
        return pcConstraints
    }

    private fun handleLocalIceCandidate(candidate: IceCandidate) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Local ICE candidate: $candidate")
        signaler.sendCandidate(candidate.sdpMLineIndex, candidate.sdpMid, candidate.sdp)
    }

    private fun addRemoteStream(stream: MediaStream) {
        onStatusChangedListener(VideoCallStatus.CONNECTED)
        Log.i(TAG, "Got remote stream: $stream")
        executor.execute {
            if (stream.videoTracks.isNotEmpty()) {
                val remoteVideoTrack = stream.videoTracks.first()
                remoteVideoTrack.setEnabled(true)
                remoteVideoTrack.addSink(VideoSink(videoRenderers.remoteRenderer))
            }
        }
    }

    private fun removeRemoteStream(@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER") _stream: MediaStream) {
        // We lost the stream, lets finish
        Log.w(TAG, "Bye")
        onStatusChangedListener(VideoCallStatus.FINISHED)
    }

    private fun handleRemoteCandidate(label: Int, id: String, strCandidate: String) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Got remote ICE candidate $strCandidate")
        executor.execute {
            val candidate = IceCandidate(id, label, strCandidate)
            peerConnection?.addIceCandidate(candidate)
        }
    }
    private fun setupMediaDevices() {
        // Ensure that the videoCapturer is initialized before calling this function
        if (videoCapturer == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "setupMediaDevices: videocall media device null")
            // Handle initialization failure, show an error message, or return.
            return
        }

        mediaStream = factory.createLocalMediaStream(STREAM_LABEL)

        mediaStream?.addTrack(setupVideoTrack(isFront))

        audioSource = factory.createAudioSource(createAudioConstraints())
        val audioTrack = factory.createAudioTrack(AUDIO_TRACK_LABEL, audioSource)

        mediaStream?.addTrack(audioTrack)
        peerConnection?.addStream(mediaStream)
    }

private fun setupVideoTrack(front: Boolean): VideoTrack? {
    val camera = if (useCamera2()) Camera2Enumerator(context) else Camera1Enumerator(false)

    videoCapturer = if (front) createFrontCameraCapturer(camera) else createBackCameraCapturer(camera)

    // Check if the videoCapturer is properly initialized
    if (videoCapturer == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupVideoTrack: videocall camera null")
        // Handle initialization failure, show an error message, or return null.
        return null
    }

    videoCapturer!!.initialize(null, context, null)

    // Create a video source and specify whether it's a screencast
    val videoSource = factory.createVideoSource(videoCapturer!!.isScreencast())

    // Start capturing video
    videoCapturer!!.startCapture(videoWidth, videoHeight, videoFPS)

    val videoRenderer = VideoSink(videoRenderers.localRenderer)

    // Create a video track using the video source
    val videoTrack = factory.createVideoTrack(VIDEO_TRACK_LABEL, videoSource)

    // Add the video renderer as a sink to the video track
    videoTrack?.addSink(videoRenderer)
    mediaStream?.addTrack(videoTrack)
    Log.d(TAG, "createFrontCameraCapturer: videocall camera 2"+videoTrack)

    return videoTrack
}

    private fun createAudioConstraints(): MediaConstraints {
        val audioConstraints = MediaConstraints()
        audioConstraints.mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googEchoCancellation", "true"))
        audioConstraints.mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googAutoGainControl", "false"))
        audioConstraints.mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googHighpassFilter", "false"))
        audioConstraints.mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googNoiseSuppression", "true"))
        return audioConstraints
    }

    private fun handleRemoteDescriptor(sdp: String) {
        if (isOfferingPeer) {
            peerConnection?.setRemoteDescription(SDPSetCallback({ setError ->
                if (setError != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "setRemoteDescription failed: $setError")
                }
            }), SessionDescription(SessionDescription.Type.ANSWER, sdp))
        } else {
            peerConnection?.setRemoteDescription(SDPSetCallback({ setError ->
                if (setError != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "setRemoteDescription failed: $setError")
                } else {
                    peerConnection?.createAnswer(SDPCreateCallback(this::createDescriptorCallback), MediaConstraints())
                }
            }), SessionDescription(SessionDescription.Type.OFFER, sdp))
        }
    }

    private fun createDescriptorCallback(result: SDPCreateResult) {
        when (result) {
            is SDPCreateSuccess -> {
                peerConnection?.setLocalDescription(SDPSetCallback({ setResult ->
                    Log.i(TAG, "SetLocalDescription: $setResult")
                }), result.descriptor)
                signaler.sendSDP(result.descriptor.description)
            }
            is SDPCreateFailure -> Log.e(TAG, "Error creating offer: ${result.reason}")
        }
    }

    private fun onMessage(message: ClientMessage) {
        when (message) {

            is SDPMessage -> {
                handleRemoteDescriptor(message.sdp)
            }
            is ICEMessage -> {
                handleRemoteCandidate(message.label, message.id, message.candidate)
            }
            is PeerLeft -> {
                onStatusChangedListener(VideoCallStatus.FINISHED)
            }
        }
    }


    fun terminate() {
        signaler.close()
        try {
            videoCapturer?.stopCapture()
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
        }

        videoCapturer?.dispose()
        videoSource?.dispose()

        audioSource?.dispose()

        peerConnection?.dispose()

        factory.dispose()

        eglBase.release()
    }

    private var isFront = true

    fun toggleCamera() {
        isFront = !isFront
        mediaStream?.removeTrack(videoTrack)
        videoTrack?.dispose()
        mediaStream?.addTrack(setupVideoTrack(isFront))
    }


    private fun createFrontCameraCapturer(enumerator: CameraEnumerator): VideoCapturer? {
        val deviceNames = enumerator.deviceNames
        //find the front facing camera and return it.
        deviceNames
                .filter { enumerator.isFrontFacing(it) }
                .mapNotNull { enumerator.createCapturer(it, null) }
                .forEach { return it }

        return null
    }

    private fun createBackCameraCapturer(enumerator: CameraEnumerator): VideoCapturer? {
        // Front facing camera not found, try something else

        val deviceNames = enumerator.deviceNames
        //find the front facing camera and return it.
        deviceNames
                .filter { enumerator.isBackFacing(it) }
                .mapNotNull {
                    Logging.d(TAG, "Creating other camera capturer.")
                    enumerator.createCapturer(it, null)
                }
                .forEach { return it }

        Toast.makeText(context, "No back camera found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return createFrontCameraCapturer(enumerator)
    }

    private fun useCamera2(): Boolean {
        return Camera2Enumerator.isSupported(context)
    }

    companion object {

        fun connect(context: Context, id: String, isOffer: Boolean, videoRenderers: VideoRenderers, callback: (VideoCallStatus) -> Unit): VideoCallSession {
            val firebaseHandler = FirebaseSignaler(id)
            return VideoCallSession(context, isOffer, callback, firebaseHandler, videoRenderers)
        }

        private const val STREAM_LABEL = "remoteStream"
        private const val VIDEO_TRACK_LABEL = "remoteVideoTrack"
        private const val AUDIO_TRACK_LABEL = "remoteAudioTrack"
        private const val TAG = "VideoCallSession"
        private val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }
```

Expecting to videocall between two users